# Configure translation file format and folder structure

Tags: symfony, translation

I use the **php-translation** bundle.

When I edit a value for a translation key in the debug bar and sync it, then a `.xlf` file gets automatically created in the `app/Resources/translations` folder and it provides the translation key with value that I edited in the debug bar.

What I actually want to have is that the value of the translation key gets updated in the `.yml` file in the `src/UserBundle/Resources/translations` file that I have already created.

Is there any possibility to configure the bundle that way?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the output folder. From the [php-translation documentation](http://php-translation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/symfony/index.html#configuration):

```
translation:
  locales: ["en", "fr", "sv"]
  configs:
    app:
      dirs: ["%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/views", "%kernel.root_dir%/../src"]
      output_dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/translations"
      excluded_names: ["*TestCase.php", "*Test.php"]
      excluded_dirs: [cache, data, logs]
```

Comment: Sorry I was not specific enough. This configuration doesn't effect the [Symfony Profiler UI](http://php-translation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/symfony/profiler-ui.html) that I want to configure.

Comment: Ah I see. What storage are you using? The default one? And how your config looks like.

Comment: I use the default storage. My configuration looks exactly like it is described in the [documentation](http://php-translation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/symfony/profiler-ui.html)

Comment: Then it can be a bug(uses different storage for profiler ui and for other stuff). I use the php-translation and output_dir parameter works. But I don't use symfony profiler UI.